Checking presence of Memo within a transaction with Solana-SDK
I am currently attempting to figure out a way to check for the presence of a specific memo within a transaction using just the Solana-SDK or any off-chain-based Rust crates.
Below is code that is supposed to execute this:
async fn check_single_deposit(&self, reference: &str, expected_amount: u64, current_balance: u64) -> Result<Option<u64>, SolanaServiceError> {
    let transactions = self.rpc_client
        .get_signatures_for_address(&self.node_keypair.pubkey())
        .await
        .map_err(|e| SolanaServiceError::DepositConfirmationError(e.to_string()))?;

    for signature_info in transactions {
        let signature = signature_info.signature.parse::<Signature>()
            .map_err(|e| SolanaServiceError::DepositConfirmationError(e.to_string()))?;
        
        let tx = self.rpc_client
            .get_transaction(&signature, UiTransactionEncoding::Json)
            .await
            .map_err(|e| SolanaServiceError::DepositConfirmationError(e.to_string()))?;

        if let Some(meta) = &tx.transaction.meta {
            // Check for memo in transaction instructions
            if let Some(log_messages) = meta.log_messages.as_ref() {
                if log_messages.iter().any(|msg| msg.contains(reference)) {
                    let post_balances = &meta.post_balances;
                    if post_balances.get(0) == Some(&current_balance) {
                        return Ok(Some(expected_amount));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

The purpose for this code is to allow for users to queue deposits via a memo based reference system. Similar to that of early CEX deposits. Users can send deposits from any solana address as long as the deposit contains the unique memo provided.

use solana_sdk::{
    instruction::Instruction,
    message::Message,
    memo::PROGRAM_ID as MEMO_PROGRAM_ID,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    transaction::Transaction,
};
use solana_client::rpc_client::RpcClient;
use solana_client::rpc_config::RpcTransactionConfig;
use solana_sdk::signature::Signature;
use serde_json::Value; // For JSON parsing

async fn check_single_deposit(
    &self,
    reference: &str,
    expected_amount: u64,
    current_balance: u64,
) -> Result<Option<u64>, SolanaServiceError> {
    let transactions = self.rpc_client
        .get_signatures_for_address(&self.node_keypair.pubkey())
        .await
        .map_err(|e| SolanaServiceError::DepositConfirmationError(e.to_string()))?;

    for signature_info in transactions {
        let signature = signature_info.signature.parse::<Signature>()
            .map_err(|e| SolanaServiceError::DepositConfirmationError(e.to_string()))?;
        
        let tx = self.rpc_client
            .get_transaction(&signature, UiTransactionEncoding::Json)
            .await
            .map_err(|e| SolanaServiceError::DepositConfirmationError(e.to_string()))?;

        if let Some(meta) = &tx.transaction.meta {
            // Directly inspect transaction instructions
            if let Some(instructions) = tx.transaction.transaction.message.instructions.as_ref() {
                for instruction in instructions {
                    let program_id = &tx.transaction.transaction.message.account_keys[instruction.program_id_index as usize];
                    if program_id == &MEMO_PROGRAM_ID {
                        // Decode memo data
                        let memo = String::from_utf8(instruction.data.clone()).ok()?;
                        if memo.contains(reference) {
                            let post_balances = &meta.post_balances;
                            if post_balances.get(0) == Some(&current_balance) {
                                return Ok(Some(expected_amount));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Ok(None)
}


Hey - solana_sdk does not have ::memo present. Although i believe there is spl-memo for checking the program id for example.
